# How do I access private properties from function prototype in javascript module pattern?

Tags: javascript, properties, module, prototype, private

I have been searching for a way to access private properties using the constructor module pattern. I came up with a solution that works but am not sure this is optimal.

```
mynamespace.test = function () {
    var s = null;

    // constructor function.
    var Constr = function () {
        //this.s = null;

    };

    Constr.prototype.get = function () {
        return s;
    };

    Constr.prototype.set = function (s_arg) {
        s =  s_arg;
    };

    // return the constructor.
    return new Constr;
};


var x1 = new mynamespace.test();
var x2 = new mynamespace.test();
x1.set('x1');
alert('x1 get:' + x1.get()); // returns x1
x2.set('x2');
alert('x2 get:' + x2.get()); // returns x2
alert('x1 get: ' + x1.get()); // returns x1
```

Comment: That is as good as it gets with current JavaScript. However, you shouldn't return a "new constructor" (i.e. an instance), just the constructor itself (`return Constr;`).

Comment: You **cannot** have *optimal* (e.g. make use of `prototype` inheritance) private member hiding in JavaScript. You **can** have fake private members (e.g. `this._imAPrivateMember`) with `prototype` inheritance, only. In your case, each `new mynamespace.test` you make defines a new `Contr` and a `prototype` chain on each of them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I meant to create a new instance each time since I wanted to store private properties that are shared amongst the prototype functions for a particular instantiation. Does ECMA5 address this need?

Answer (score 0):

```
mynamespace.Woman = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;

    this.getAge = function() {
        // you shouldn't ask a woman's age...
        return age;
    };

    this.setAge = function(value) {
        age = value;
    };
};

var x1 = new mynamespace.Woman("Anna", 30);
x1.setAge(31);
alert(x1.name); // Anna
alert(x1.age); // undefined
alert(x1.getAge()); // 31
```

The difference between this and your solution is that your solution will generate a new Constr every time you call namespace.test(). It's a subtle difference, but this is still preferred.

One of the differences is that you can use:

```
x1 instanceof mynamespace.Woman
```

Whereas in your solution, the type of x1 would be different from x2, since they use a different Constr.